# WSO2 APIM-2.1.0 Get accessToken which has infinity expiration time via /token api

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'v regenerated the token through wso2-store UI by keeping the validity period `-1` or `-3600`. The new token is getting generated which has infinity validity period.  
As soon as I do the REST call to https://ip-addr:8243/token, it gives me the new access-token having `"expires_in":3600`. 
Is there any way to get the same accessToken which has validity period of infinity ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have used the password grant type when calling the token endpoint which cannot be used to define expiry time by our own.

When we are generating the access token with infinite expiry time through UI it is calling the client credentials grant type.

Therefore use client credentials grant type with specifying the token validity period with a minus value to get a access token with infinite expiry time. Sample curl is as below.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials&validity_period=-2&client_id=akp8cfk0lqMbjPY88ODpTOK8mooa&client_secret=tO1gtTRLOGyZVOfNIepXpEaIum4a"  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's working for setting token as non expiring. 
Let's say I've called token API, received then access_token. But next time I'm making a same token API call, it's giving new access_token. How can I get the existing non-expiring token by calling token API?

Comment: Make sure you have the same set of scopes in both requests.